# appfog is unable to install node.js application

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, appfog, bower

I can't get my node.js application to work on appfog. I create a new application on their website. Then in my application directory i run:

af login <-- Works

and then:

af update myapplicationname

I get this error: No such file or directory - /Users/Name/myapplicationname/node_modules/bower

I don't use bower. I tryed use bower but i removed it and the files.
My package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "myapplicationname",
    "description": "My application",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.x"

    }
}
```

I user version 0.8.14 of node which should be supported by appfog.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the following and managed to fix it by:

1) removing the node_modules folder (`rm -rf node_modules`)

2) reinstall all the dependencies (`npm install`)

3) recreate the shrinkwrap.json (`npm shrinkwrap`)